# WP Как ускорить AJAX выдачу?

Tags: wordpress, ajax

Есть ли какие-то способы ускорить `ajax` выдачи контента карточек с биографией пользователя?
Код получения вот такой

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".bio-item").on("click", function () {
        let name = $(this).find(".bio-item__name").text();
        //let imgUrl = $(this).find('.bio-item__img img').attr("src");
        let locations = $(this).find(".bio-item__location").text();
        let positions = $(this).find(".bio-item__title").text();
        let currentMemberPostId = +$(this).data('member');


        let currentPopup = $('.bio-modal');

        let currPopupDescriptionField = currentPopup.find(".bio-modal__text");
        currPopupDescriptionField.text(''); // cleared from previous request

        $.ajax({
            url: myCode.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'get_post_description',
                nonce: myCode.nonce,
                post_id: currentMemberPostId, // ID post team
            },
            success: function (response) {
                currPopupDescriptionField.html(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

        currentPopup.find('.bio-modal__name').text(name);
        currentPopup.find('.bio-modal__title').text(positions);
        currentPopup.find('.bio-modal__location').text(locations);

    })

});
```

запрос в базу

```
function custom_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('team-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/wp-assets/js/team_page.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('team-script', 'myCode', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('nonce-current-site')
    ));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts');

// Get Member Description  AJAX
add_action('wp_ajax_get_post_description', 'get_post_description');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_description', 'get_post_description');
function get_post_description()
{
    if (empty($_POST['nonce'])) {
        wp_die('0');
    }
    /// Nonce code checking
    if (check_ajax_referer('nonce-current-site', 'nonce', false)) {

        if (isset($_POST['post_id'])) {
            $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
            $description = get_post($post_id)->post_content;
            echo $description;
        }

    } else {
        wp_die("Success denied", '', 403);
    }

    wp_die();
}



function set_default_editor_mode() {
    return 'tinymce'; // Визуальный режим
}
add_filter('wp_default_editor', 'set_default_editor_mode');
```

От нажатия кнопки до получения и вставки контента ~2сек и это на локальном сервере.

Comment: Замеряйте время работы  php скрипта. Замеряйте время запроса. Анализируйтеч что из этого и где тормозит. Профайлеров в наше время полно.  Возможно надо в БД что-то менять. Из кода производительность на удалённом компе нельзя оценить

Comment: Кода у вас примерно ноль, что в JS, что в PHP. Выполняться должно мгновенно. Задержки связаны с загрузкой ядра и плагинов (да, при ajax грузятся все плагины). Два подхода - либо оптимизировать сайт, либо использовать SHORTINIT: https://wp-kama.ru/id_3014/podgruzhaem-sredu-wordpress-s-minimalnoy-nagruzkoy-konstanta-shortinit.html

Answer (score -2):

... Итак, в вп существует несколько способов оптимизации выдачи данных через AJAX. Код выглядит вполне себе, но есть несколько моментов, которые можно улучшить для более быстрой выдачи контента. Вот несколько рекомендаций:

**Кэширование:** Один из способов ускорить AJAX-запросы - это кэширование. Вы можете кэшировать результаты запросов, чтобы не выполнять один и тот же запрос снова и снова. Это может существенно сократить нагрузку на сервер и время ожидания. Вам могут пригодиться функции кэширования, такие как wp_cache_set и wp_cache_get.

**Оптимизация базы данных:** Убедитесь, что ваша база данных оптимизирована. Вы можете использовать плагины для оптимизации базы данных или выполнять это вручную.

**Асинхронная загрузка:** Вы можете рассмотреть вариант асинхронной загрузки контента, даже до того, как пользователь кликнет на карточку. Таким образом, контент уже будет доступен, когда пользователь решит его увидеть.

**Использование кэша на клиентской стороне:** Если контент в карточках мало меняется, вы можете рассмотреть возможность кэширования его на стороне клиента. Это позволит избежать постоянных запросов на сервер для одних и тех же данных.

**Минимизация данных:** Попробуйте уменьшить количество данных, которые передаются по AJAX. Возможно, вам не нужно передавать всю структуру поста, а только его содержимое.

**Асинхронная предзагрузка:** Вы можете предзагрузить данные, например, в момент, когда пользователь наводит курсор на карточку. Таким образом, при клике на карточку, данные уже будут доступны и не потребуется дополнительный AJAX-запрос.

Консолидация запросов: В некоторых случаях, если у вас есть несколько последовательных AJAX-запросов, вы можете объединить их в один запрос, чтобы уменьшить задержку из-за ожидания.

**Оптимизация сервера:** Обратите внимание на общую производительность вашего сервера. Если сервер медленно обрабатывает запросы, это также может вызвать задержки в выдаче данных.

**Асинхронные задачи:** Если задача получения данных очень ресурсоемкая, вы можете рассмотреть возможность использования асинхронных задач, таких как WP Cron, для предварительной выгрузки данных.

И, наконец, помните, что некоторые задержки могут быть вызваны не только серверной частью, но и скоростью интернет-соединения пользователя, а также производительностью самого браузера.

вот оптимизированный код для вашего скрипта team_page.js и функции get_post_description:

```
// team_page.js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.member-card').on('click', function() {
        var post_id = $(this).data('post-id');
        
        $.ajax({
            url: myCode.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'get_post_description',
                nonce: myCode.nonce,
                post_id: post_id
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Обработка полученного описания
                $('.description-container').html(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Ошибка при загрузке описания');
            }
        });
    });
});



// functions.php
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('team-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/wp-assets/js/team_page.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('team-script', 'myCode', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('nonce-current-site')
    ));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts');

// Get Member Description AJAX
add_action('wp_ajax_get_post_description', 'get_post_description');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_description', 'get_post_description');
function get_post_description() {
    check_ajax_referer('nonce-current-site', 'nonce');

    if (isset($_POST['post_id'])) {
        $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
        $description = get_post($post_id)->post_content;
        echo $description;
    }

    wp_die();
}

function set_default_editor_mode() {
    return 'tinymce'; // Визуальный режим
}
add_filter('wp_default_editor', 'set_default_editor_mode');
```

Comment: Спасибо, за объяснения с оптимизацией, можно ещё пару слов про "оптимизированный код" который вы тут написали? Я не очень понимаю в чем тут оптимизация ?

Comment: Не надо сюда постить ответы ChatGPT. Делитесь своими знаниями.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 да нет тут никакой оптимизации. Есть копипаста дурацкого ответа ChatGPT.